# Is it possible to run hadoop fs -getmerge in S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I have an Elastic Map Reduce job which is writing some files in S3 and I want to concatenate all the files to produce a unique text file.

Currently I'm manually copying the folder with all the files to our HDFS (hadoop fs copyFromLocal), then I'm running hadoop fs -getmerge and hadoop fs copyToLocal to obtain the file.

is there anyway to use hadoop fs directly on S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this response about getmerge is incorrect.  getmerge expects a local destination and will not work with S3.  It throws an `IOException` if you try and responds with -getmerge: Wrong FS:.

Usage:

```
hadoop fs [generic options] -getmerge [-nl] <src> <localdst>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way (**if you are generating a small file that fits on the master machine**) is to do the following:

1. Merge the file parts into a single file onto the local machine ([Documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge))

   ```
   hadoop fs -getmerge hdfs://[FILE] [LOCAL FILE]
   ```
2. Copy the result file to S3, *and then delete the local file* ([Documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#moveFromLocal))

   ```
   hadoop dfs -moveFromLocal [LOCAL FILE] s3n://bucket/key/of/file
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried the getmerge command myself but `hadoop fs` commands on EMR cluster nodes support S3 paths just like HDFS paths. For example, you can SSH into the master node of your cluster and run:

```
hadoop fs -ls s3://<my_bucket>/<my_dir>/
```

The above command will list of out all the S3 objects under the specified directory path.

I would expect `hadoop fs -getmerge` to work the same way. So, just use full S3 paths (starting with s3://) instead of HDFS paths.

Comment: `hadoop fs -getmerge` can only merge TO the local filesystem, not s3